# Definition of map preserve the measure : why is it $\mu(T^{-1}(A))=\mu(A)$ and not $\mu(T(A))=\mu(A)$.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal B,\mathbb P)$ a probability space. In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure-preserving_dynamical_system#Definition), they say that a map $T:X\to X$ preserve the measure if $$\mathbb P(T^{-1}(A))=\mu(A),$$
for all $A\in \mathcal B$.

---

Why a definition as $\mathbb P(T(A))=\mathbb P(A)$ would not work ? It looks more natural, no ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image of a measurabe set under a measurable transformation may not be measurable but the inverse image is always measurable (by definition of measurability).

If $T$ is bijective and $T^{-1}$ is also measurable thee the two conditions are identical.